# Can't use vector::assign with 1 parameter on vs code mac

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

At first I thought there was something wrong with my code, but even this gets compiler errors and says that I need to provide 2 arguments:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>


std::vector<int>v;

int main()
{
    int m;
    std::cin>>m;
    v.assign(m);

}
```

If I use `v.assign(m,-1);` instead of `v.assign(m);`, it compiles and runs just fine.

Here are the error messages:

```
    error: no matching member function for call to 'assign'
v.assign(m);
~~^~~~

~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:623:9: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
        assign(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last);
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:633:9: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
        assign(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last);
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:635:10: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
    void assign(size_type __n, const_reference __u);
```

What should I do?

Comment: You want `push_back`, not `assign`.

Comment: @Nathan But this works alright for all my friends and with online compilers? I wanted to avoid using push_back if possible since it takes a bit longer for me to write it. I understand that it's not much anyways, but isn't there a way to make this work? Edit: Never mind I was just being dumb. Sorry.

Comment: assign(3,m) append 3 m to the vector. if just want to assign 1 m use assign(1,m) or assign({m}). and of cause your need is just push_back(m).

Comment: Tell me which overload should work? Please learn to [inspect documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign).

Comment: @Iamme Can you share an online compiler where this works?  `assign` has never had an overload that takes one argument.  FWIW, the time to write a program is a small fraction of the time it takes to design, debug, and build a program.  Taking a little longer to write won't really make much of a difference in the long run.

Comment: @Iamme show an online compile where this works. I don't believe you until you prove me wrong.

Comment: the elegant way for you  v={m} if you use c++11

Comment: BTW: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Nathan Yes, turns out I was being dumb lol. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I guess I was just being dumb/super bad with memory. I tried it again and don't know how I remembered it that way before. Sorry about that

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'm trying to change the size to m and assign -1 to every element of the vector. I guess I shouldn't be lazy and just use a for loop or ` memset` . Like, a for loop isn't even that long, I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for [std::vector.assign()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign). `assign(n, e)` will fill the vector with `n` copies of `e`. There is no 1 argument call to `assign`.

Comment: I thought `  count`  was a single parameter, that confused me a bit.

Comment: What is your goal? To add a single element to a vector? To change the size of the vector to size `m`?

Comment: To resize the vector to ` m`  and assign -1 to every element of the vector. I guess I should use a for loop or ` memset`  ?

Comment: @Iamme This sounds like a perfect use case for `assign`, why does `v.assign(m, -1);` not work for this exact purpose?

Comment: ... Me being dumb again, I guess. I don't remember why I tried to make assign work with only one parameter.

Comment: @Iamme Sometimes talking to other people about your problem makes the solution obvious. Hope your code is a success!